# Dual monitors- Running Outlook and opening emails in the same monitor

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, multiple-monitors

So I'm running windows 7 and just installed dual monitors. I need to have Outlook open on one monitor and use the other for other applications. But when I click anything in Outlook to open it it always goes to the other monitor. Is there any way around this? I know many people say that Windows "remembers" where you close an application or window and will open that type of window in the same place. That seems to work with everything except my emails and Outlook!

Has anyone conquered this problem before or know where to start?

Comment: Strange. Mine works as expected using Outlook 2010 on Windows 7. Open an email, drag it to where you want it, close it. Open another email and it should go to the same location. Appointments, contacts etc will each remember their own "home" location separately.

Answer (score 9):

I was just researching the exact issue.

I opened outlook on the primary monitor and dragged it to the second monitor. Each time I opened an individual email from the secondary monitor, the email opened on the primary.

So, what I did was:

1. I had outlook opened on my secondary monitor and the email opened on the primary. I wanted the individual email to open on the secondary.
2. I dragged the open email from the primary over to the secondary and closed the invidividual email. Windows 7 remembered that action.

Now, the outlook application and each individual email open on the seconday.

Answer (score 7):

Don't have the window maximized (just restored, or you can't move it), then move it to where you want it, the hold SHIFT and close it. You probably do not need the SHIFT key, but that is a common way for Microsoft to REALLY save a location. Then test.

Comment: On Windows 7 it does not matter if the window is maximised or not, you can still move it by drag and drop, with a few odd exceptions such as Excel 2007, but not Outlook. Where did you get this odd idea about Shift+Closing a window to REALLY save the location?

Comment: Shift button works for me

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Display Fusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/). I use it with my dual-monitor setup and it works really well. It even has an option for you to specify which monitor programs open in.